# Is there a table in the SCCM database that stores the device type information?

Tags: sccm

I will like to be able to differentiate between a desktop, server, virtual server and I was wondering if there is a table in the SCCM database e.g. Device Type that would store this information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the view "v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM". Or use the v_R_System one (attributes 'Operating_System_Name_and0').